# how custom management work in django and can fill database with csv?

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django with the book web development with django
In the second chapter of the book, the author fills the database with a csv file.
Can anyone explain this file and how the django custom command works?

python code address:
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Web-Development-with-Django/blob/master/Chapter02/final/bookr/reviews/management/commands/loadcsv.py

csv address:
https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Web-Development-with-Django/blob/master/Chapter02/final/bookr/reviews/management/commands/WebDevWithDjangoData.csv

i just know how it work

Answer (score 1):

All details are in Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

But to put it in a nutshell, there are 2 major methods of a django.core.management.base.BaseCommand:

- `add_arguments`: you will use it to add optional argument(s) to your custom command: `python manage.py custom_command --argument1 --argument2`
- `handle`: In this method, you'll catch arguments of your commands (which are in the `options` var (dict). So in your dictionary, you'll have `argument1` and `argument2` with eventually a value (depending of your argument setup)

Comment: when i run python manage.py loadcsv --csv reviews/management/commands/WebDevWithDjangoData.csv its give an error return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: reviews_publisher